# RenderPartial via Ajax(jquery) and renders with incorrect model. (BUG)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a really unusual issue where even though the debugger claims to be rendering the partial view with new newly created model in the controller, it renders it with the model values from the data that was passed in from the post.

A modelstate.clear(); fixes the issue but surely this is not correct.

Any ideas?

Calling Script

```
$("#registerSubmit").live("click", function (e) {
            if ($("#registerForm").valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'home/Register',
                    data: $("#registerForm").serialize(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $("#registerHolder").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(Register model)
        {
            var t = new Register();
            t.EmailAddress = "test";
            t.Password = "1";
            t.VerifyPassword = "2";

            return PartialView("p_register2", t);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify values that are being POSTed you will need to remove them from the model state or HTML helpers will always use the POSTed values and not the ones in your model. That's how HTML helpers work and this behavior is by design. For example a `Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailAddress)` helper sees that there is a POSTed `EmailAddress` value and it will use this value instead of the one you are passing in the model.

So, you should either remove the values that you want to modify from the model state or write your own HTML helpers:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Register model)
{
    var t = new Register();
    t.EmailAddress = "test";
    t.Password = "1";
    t.VerifyPassword = "2";
    ModelState.Remove("EmailAddress");
    ModelState.Remove("Password");
    ModelState.Remove("VerifyPassword ");
    return PartialView("p_register2", t);
}
```

and looking at this action one might ask himself the question: what's the purpose of the Register model you are using as action argument? So:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var t = new Register();
    t.EmailAddress = "test";
    t.Password = "1";
    t.VerifyPassword = "2";
    return PartialView("p_register2", t);
}
```

Comment: There is no point to the passed in register model, basically I'm going to validate the model and based upon the result of that I was going to either return the current model for further input from the user, or return a json result so I could programatically perform other actions.

In doing that I noticed the behaviour mentioned above, now you have cleared that up for me, I can get back to business.

Thanks

Comment: @RubbleFord, as a matter of fact whether your controller action takes a Register model as argument doesn't really matter. The HTML helpers in the partial will still use the old POSTed values when binding and not the ones you are setting in your new model. So you might need to remove them from ModelState for this to work.

Comment: Yep, after you told me the behaviour was by design I went and took a look through the MVC 3 source. It's definitely one to remember as at the outset it looked very odd.